# Rule system using Tree

Tags: tree, stack, rules

I have rules represented as a `Tree`

```
root    provider airline flightCode action
----    -------- ------- ---------- ------
├────── A
│       └─────── QG
│                ├────── QG-123     x=1
│                └────── *          x=2
└────── *                     
        ├─────── QG
        │        └────── QG-234     x=3
        ├─────── GA
        │        └────── *          x=4
        └─────── *            
                 └────── JT-200     x=5
```

note: wildcard (`*`) means any value is allowed

And a fact represented as a `Stack`

```
+------------+
| provider   |
+------------+
| airline    |
+------------+
| flightCode |
+------------+
```

I have 6 test cases with the following facts

```
no provider airline flightCode result (x)
-- -------- ------- ---------- ----------
1  A        QG      QG-123      1
2  B        GA      GA-123      4
3  A        JT      JT-200      5
4  A        JT      JT-500      not found (exception)
5  B        QG      QG-234      3
6  B        JT      JT-123      not found (exception)
```

How is the logic to evaluate above test cases to achieve their respective result?